# Remote Tomcat .war deployment base URL change

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I was developing an application using my **localhost** apache-tomcat webserver. And when I was deploying my application using intellij idea, **I had no problems with URL's, to reach an app I used URL**:

> localhost:8080

But now I tried to deploy my application on **remote** server installed on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS, and I got a problem with base URL change. I created a .war artifact and copied it with additional libraries to webapps folder of remote tomcat. The name of my project is **Spider**. After starting tomcat on remote server, **I can only reach my application using URL**:

> serverIpAddress:8080/Spider

But because I have a /Spider in my base URL all my links on the pages does not lead to appropriate controllers, and I have 404 error. For example working link is: `serverIpAddress:8080/googleApi`, but link leads to `serverIpAddress:8080/Spider/googleApi`.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you in advance, and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using absolute links, which is very bad practice. If you will have some proxy or load balancer before your app it will not work also. So the solution is to use only relative paths in all view pages. Another thing which is not good is using case sensitive characters, I would personally use only small ones especially on Linux platform. If you really want your app available as root you can deploy it by overriding ROOT directory in tomcat weapp, but please be aware that it will destroy tomcat standard Management GUI